# Check if user is signed in from React that uses express passport backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I want React  to know if a user signed in or not.

I'm using `passport-github`, and currently a user can sign in. However, **react does not know** who is logged in or not, and i want react to check if a user is authenticated.

***I want to know a way for react to catch the set token and save it to localStorage , and use that as a way to see if user is logged in or not.***

I have a vague idea on how to do this in react.

for example if

`token != null`

log user in

**routes/users.js**

```
router.get('/auth/github', passport.authenticate('github',  { session: true, scope: ['profile'] }) );

router.get('/auth/github/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    var token = jwt.sign({ id: req.user.id},  'nodeauthsecret');
        res.cookie("jwt", token, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 10*1000*60*60*24)});
    res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:3000/dashboard');
    console.log(token) // renders a token, how can react fetch this token ?
    console.log('this works');
});
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import axios from 'axios';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: 20
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },

  chip: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: ""
    }

}

componentWillMount(){
  // example code

  // fetch token from backend
  fetch('/api/token')
    .then( (res) => {
        localStorage.setItem() // set token as localStorage
    })
}



  render() {

    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (

      <div className="App">

        <Navbar />



      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you basically have this mapped out already. The server returns the token to the client after logging in. The client sets the token in localStorage. React can now reference this token where it needs to to display UI accordingly.

It would be nice to have have an `isLoggedIn` prop exposed on react context or set in a redux store etc so you can access the prop throughout any of the applications components

Comment: how would i fetch the token from the auth/github/callback in react ?

Comment: have that callback return the created token to to the client.  ie 
  return res.json({
    status: 200,
     token,
});

Comment: i dont understand, im just going to figure this out by code. thx though scott.